# Error when adding contacts from Google Spreadsheets to Google Contacts

Tags: google-sheets

I tried making a script on Google Spreadsheets to add new contacts based on a spreadsheet and add them to the "adicionar marcador" group, it ended up like this::

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Planilha de cadastro')
var headerRows = 1;
var MaxRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = dataRange.getValues();     
data.splice(0, headerRows);       

function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Contatos')
  .addItem('Adicionar Contatos', 'addContact')
  .addToUi();
}    

function addContact() {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = data[i];
  var firstName = row[1];
  var lastName = row[2];
  var email = row[3];
  var phone = row[4];
  var job = row[5];
  var address2 = row[6];
  var Age = row [7];
  var obs = row [8];
  var group = row[10];
  
  
  contact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, email);
  contact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, phone);
  
  contact.setNotes(obs)
  contact.addCompany('', job)
  contact.addCustomField("Idade", Age);
  contact.addCustomField("Endereço", address2)
  
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
  group.addContact(contact);

  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Adicionar marcador')
  group.addContact(contact);

  }

}
```

But when I try adding contacts by using the function addContact it returns me an error message. Any idea on what is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You have declared group three times. Remove the var on the last two. I have been trying to run your code and it is not giving an error - just not doing anything????

Comment: Index of array starts with zero so firstName = row[0]  etc.

Comment: found the contacts were added under other contacts???

Comment: It was just a generic error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see comments above about declaring variables multiple times and arrays starting with zero. This added the data (and not the headings) and placed the contacts into the group from the spreadsheet. I created the group first.

```
function createContactGroup()    {   // this works
  let group = ContactsApp.createContactGroup('apps-script');
  console.log('group.getName(): ', group.getName() );
}
  
function addContact() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('contact')
  const headerRows = 1;
  let MaxRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  let data = dataRange.getValues();     
  console.log('data: ', data);
  
  let row, firstName, lastName, email, phone, job, address2, Age, obs, group;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)         {                           // top row is header
    row = data[i];
    firstName = row[0];
    lastName = row[1];
    email = row[2];
    console.log('fname: ', firstName, ' lname: ', lastName, ' email: ', email );
    phone = row[3];
    job = row[4];
    address2 = row[5];
    Age = row[6];
    obs = row[7];
    group = row[8];
    console.log('group: ', group );
    
    try    {
      contact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, email);
    }  catch (err)  {
      console.log('createContact err: ', err );
    }
    
    contact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, phone);
    contact.setNotes(obs)
    contact.addCompany('', job)
    contact.addCustomField("Idade", Age);
    contact.addCustomField("Endereço", address2)
    
    addToGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup(group);
    addToGroup.addContact(contact);
  
//    var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Adicionar marcador')
//    group.addContact(contact);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I made a few addaptations to my case and it worked flawlessly! Thanks for the tips also, it will help me a lot!